# Javascript: Push Filtered Array to Existing Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I have a small todo app here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ccLm46sn/

Two arrays, one contains completed tasks, the other archived tasks.

Whenever I execute the function **archiveCompleted** I want all completed tasks to be pushed on to the array with the archived tasks and the completed array then deleted.

Something like this:

```
this.tasks.archived.push({
    this.tasks.current.filter(function(task) {
        return task.completed;
    });
});
```

But it does not work.

This here works fine, by overwriting the archived array with the completed array:

```
this.tasks.archived = this.tasks.current.filter(function(task) {
    return task.completed;
});
```

But I don't want to overwrite the archived array, just to push into that:

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccLm46sn/

Comment: how about -  this.tasks.archived = this.tasks.archived.concat(this.tasks.current.filter(function(task) {
    return task.completed;
});)

Comment: it is working for me , Please make a fiddle with the buggy code

Comment: @TonyRaoulIscaros His fiddle is "working". Complete one task, archive it then do it with another. The first completed task will disappear from the archived ones.

Comment: No I mean the push method is working , okay now i figure out more than one element cause the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use concat to merge the the archived tasks with the completed ones.

```
// assigns to the archived object the completed tasks object
var completedTasks = this.tasks.current.filter(function(task) {
    return task.completed;
});
this.tasks.archived = this.tasks.archived.concat(completedTasks);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pto9y7js/)

Answer (score 4):

You can change your function like this:

```
this.tasks.archived.push.apply(this.tasks.archived,
this.tasks.current.filter(function(task) {
    return task.completed;
}));
```

`.apply` is used to combine arrays here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xsmag2w/1/)

Comment: That's a nice solution, but the fiddle doesn't work. The above code is correct. There is an extra pair of braces '()'  in the fiddle.

Comment: this is the best solution. I never new about "push.apply". Thanks @brso05

Comment: @khichar.anil no problem!

Comment: @khichar.anil `apply` is a function method and can be called on any function. It is not specific to `push`. Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

may be like this:

```
this.tasks.archived = this.tasks.archived.concat(this.tasks.current.filter(function(task) {
            return task.completed;
        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the part I changed in your function:

```
var completed_tasks = this.tasks.current.filter(function(task) {
    return task.completed;
});
for (var i = 0; i < completed_tasks.length; i++) {
    this.tasks.archived.push(completed_tasks[i]);
}
```

And it seems to work. Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccLm46sn/1/

I don't know if it is the best and most elegant solution, but it works as far as I have tested it.